# UIWebView is ignoring cookies?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am creating an app for the iPhone that fetches a specific page from a website, but to be able to view this site you need to log in with a username and a password.

I've created this code:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.wdg-hamburg.de";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

NSString *post = @"name=loginname&pass=pass&form_id=user_login&op=Anmelden";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[vPlan loadRequest:request];
```

But I am not logged in at the UIWebView!

I am logging `NSHTTPCookieStorage` to the console and it shows me the necessary cookie, but I dont get logged in.

Does anybody knows how I can fix that?

Kind regards,

A. Miladinovic

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Have you managed to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the cookie in the header?

```
NSArray* cookies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cookie, nil];
NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
```